# My Expo project caching image automatically

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I haven't implemented any caching method for images.I'm using simple Image and ImageBackground components from 'react-native' library. Can anyone explain how is my Image cached?

I'm using expo v30.0.2

Comment: The React Native Image component is doing the work for you, however you can implement your own cashing system

Answer (score 1):

Android will automatically cache remote images. If you want to prevent that from happening, then you can append a time stamp to the image uri, forcing it to always retrieve the latest version.

```js
{ uri: `${imageURI}?time=${Date.now()}` }
```